# SQL: Create Column (MySQL/PHPMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

With the query:

```
SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.SensorID, TableA.Value, SensorIDs.Name, TableA.timestamp
FROM TableA
JOIN SensorIDs
ON TableA.SensorID = SensorIDs.ID  // column 'Name' is in 'SensorIDs'
```

My result table looks like this:

```
ID | SensorID | Value  | Name | timestamp
 1 |  1       |  5     |  A   |  1000
 2 |  2       |  10    |  B   |  1000
 3 |  3       |  0     |  C   |  1000
 4 |  1       |  1     |  A   |  2000
 5 |  2       |  2     |  B   |  2000
 6 |  3       |  6     |  C   |  2000
[..]
```

Is there a way to change my SQL query to get a table like this:

```
 A | B  | C | timestamp
 5 | 10 | 0 |   1000
 1 | 2  | 6 |   2000
```

Something with GROUP BY maybe?

EDIT: In the forseeable future there will be only these 3 values for 'Name'.

EDIT: RDBMS: MySQL-native (InnoDB), PHPMyAdmin

EDIT: Forgot to add column "SensorID" in the result.

Comment: This is called a "Pivot" in RDBMS-speak. Please share what RDBMS you are using so we can help guide (sql server, mysql, postgres, oracle, teradata, snowflake, etc). Each platform has different ways to write this logic.

Comment: What's expected to happen if name D also is found in the table?

Comment: "JOIN....// adds the column 'Name' to the result."  => not true.  Also you should not use `*` in a SELECT query, but specify the individual column names.

Comment: thx @JNevill: I'm using phpMyAdmin on my server, and I read "phpMyAdmin allows relationships (similar to foreign keys) using MySQL-native (InnoDB) methods when available and falling back on special phpMyAdmin-only features when needed."

Comment: @Luuk alright, check, I will do better from now on.

Comment: Good point @jarlh could be NULL. In the forseeable future there will be only these 3 values. But if we can make it future proof, even better.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, by creating a PIVOT table with the tutorial I found here:
https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-create-pivot-table-in-mysql/

```
SELECT time,
sum(IF(SensorID=1, Value, NULL)) AS Sensor1,
sum(IF(SensorID=2, Value, NULL)) AS Sensor2,
sum(IF(SensorID=3, Value, NULL)) AS Sensor3,
sum(IF(SensorID=4, Value, NULL)) AS Sensor4
FROM TableA
GROUP BY time
```